# "Import error database/sql" for sql package

Tags: go, revel

"Import error database/sql" for sql package.
I wanna use connect method on the controller.
I think need to install sql package.

```
controllers/gorm.go

import (
 "database/sql"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
"github.com/revel/revel"
"myapp/app/models"
"log"
)
```

add database/sql and try import.
but the error has occurred.

error

```
Revel engine is NOT listening on.. localhost:58929
/Users/toshi/gocode/src/myapp/app/controllers/gorm.go
ERROR 16:10:50 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  
error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/gorm.go:4): imported and not used: \"database/sql\"" 
/Users/toshi/gocode/src/myapp/app/controllers/gorm.go
ERROR 16:11:49 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  
error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/gorm.go:4): imported and not used: \"database/sql\""
```

app path
    /Users/toshi/gocode/src/myapp

sql-driver path
    /Users/toshi/gocode/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

http://rabbitfoot141.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/05/000551
(reference)

Comment: Remove `"database/sql"` import if you don't use it. In the referenced article they are using `sql.Open` so there the import is required. But if your file does not contain anything that references `sql` then do not import it.